# Is it possible to hook automator to the "before download" event in Safari?

Tags: safari, automator

I find that I desperately NEED Safari to ask me where I would like something saved (and allow me to rename it) (you know.. a Save As dialog) before it is downloaded - on an individual, download by download basis.  This MUST be the default action for downloading a file; Modifier keys and right-clicks are unacceptable.

Safari does not appear to have this option available to me.

So, I am open to suggestions.  Is there a way to do this with Automator?  Is there a file system trick to accomplish this?  Safari Extension?  Anything?

Perhaps an http/s proxy program that accomplishes this?

Comment: I guess being prompted *after* the file has been downloaded is not an option, is it?

Comment: @Thecafremo: you would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can hold down the control key or click with your right mouse button and select save as... 
But I must admit that doesn't work always because some downloads aren't clicked on.
I personally dislike this solution because you have to click more ( but save as already gives you more to click then needed in my opinion ;) )

You can do this with this workaround using automator:

> 1. Open the Automator tool
> 2. Create a new "Folder Action" type document.
> 3. Assign the Folder Action to the Downloads folder.
> 4. Add these actions (in order): Move Finder Items, Reveal Finder Items,
>      Name Single Item.
> 5. Set the "Move Finder Items" action to use the Downloads folder as it's
>      default (or whichever folder you are most likely to move things to - I
>      use Downloads because most of the time I'm moving files into an
>      archive structure and want it to be easy to skip this process by just
>      hitting Return and leaving the file in Downloads when I don't do
>      that.)
> 6. Open the options for the "Move Finder Items" action and tick the
>      checkbox for "Show this action when the workflow runs."
> 7. Open the options for the "Name Single Item" action and tick the
>      checkbox for "Show this action when the workflow runs."

As quoted from: https://superuser.com/questions/201298/to-prompt-a-folder-location-when-safari-downloads-a-file

Comment: I've seen this solution before - and tried it.  But having the workflow be post-download presents a few issues.  First, that workflow doesnt tell you what file is being worked on - so if you have multiple downloads going on it wouldn't work well.  Second, it just isn't familiar.  It feels wrong.  Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: @SamAxe Random thought (I've never done this), what if the automator script only watched for *.download files? Or if you can't do that, make it watch for all files, but trigger an Applescript which only shows the dialogue if the input is a *.download file?